# When to use DbSet<T>.Add() vs DbSet<T>.Attach()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been using `Add()` and ran into a problem where by a parent entity was being duplicated in the database when `Add`ing a child. Using `Attach()` solved this but I would like to know why rather than blindly stumbling around.

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920111/entity-framework-4-addobject-vs-attach will hopefully answer your question

Comment: Thanks. This also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310068/1185053

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, when you use `Attach` you tell the context that the entity is already in the database, `SaveChanges` will have no effect over attached entities. `Add`, on the other hand, changes the state of the entity in the context (if it's already there) to `Added`, meaning it will **always** insert the entity in the database when you call `SaveChanges`.

That's the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why then in an auto-generated `Controller` in Edit does it use `db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified; db.SaveChanges();` and not `Attach()`?

Comment: Because when you `Attach()` an entity that is already in the **context**, as it is the case of the entity stored at the `model` variable, it sets the entity's state to `Unchanged`, therefore if you use `Attach()` for this end your entity will not be updated when you call `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 6):

> **in case of ef-core**

**Attach** is good for cases when you are adding a new entity to the database with navigational properties. **Attach** only marks newly created items as **changed**.

Let's say you are adding a new Employee to an Industry. If the industry already exists in the database it must have an ID. and the Employee you are adding is not inserted to the database yet so it does not have an ID yet (*I am talking about row IDs here*).

So what attach does is since the Industry already has an ID. Attach marks that as **Unchanged**. And your Employee who doesn't have an ID yet attach marks it as **Added**.

You can read more about this topic here: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data#attach

Comment: It should be clear that EF6 and EF-core are different here. EF6 won't mark an attached entity as `Added`.